# Some settings don't work because of their arrangement. Is it possible to workaround this?

Tags: vimrc

I try arrange settings in my .vimrc in the exact order and by using the same sectioning as if you click "Edit" (in the menu) and then "Settings Window".

There is problem that when I arrange settings in such a way, some of them don't work properly. For example:

```
" 5. Syntax, highlighting and spelling
let &colorcolumn = &textwidth

" 14. Editing text
set textwidth=78

There will be no color column.
```

```
" 25. Language specific
highlight link markdownerror normal

" 27. Various
colorscheme Slate

" Test: https://foo.com/aaa_bbb.
" The underscore should be normal color. But it won't.
```

Is there some hack, maybe a startup flag (`gvim.exe --magick`) to workaround this?

I already tried vim9script and at least in the second test case it fails too.

Comment: In the first case, the value of `&textwidth` is the default one, i.e., different from what you set at section 14. In the second case the syntax is being reset when you run `:colorscheme`, so you must issue a highlight command *after* changing colorscheme.

Comment: And to answer your question: no, there is no workaround for this. You can't use a variable *before* defining it and you can't expect the syntax to be the same *after* your colorscheme command alters it.

Comment: why don't you simply change the order of those settings? E.g First define the text width and then set the colorcolumn setting and first set the colorscheme and then highlight the markdown?

Comment: One way to keep the order if you really want it would be to use `set colorcolumn=78`, and then later `let &textwidth = &colorcolumn`. For the highlight and colorscheme you could put it in an autocmd: `autocmd Filetype markdown highlight link markdownerror normal`, so it gets run every time a markdown file is opened. There's also the `colorscheme` event to run things after a `colorscheme` is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Tournoji mentioned in the comments, should you wish to keep the desired order, you can use autocommands.

These commands will run on a specific event. For this specific question, you can use the `OptionSet`, `ColorScheme`, and `Filetype` events, which will run when an option, colorscheme, or filetype is changed. Specifically,

```
" 5. Syntax, highlighting and spelling
autocmd OptionSet textwidth let &colorcolumn = &textwidth

" 14. Editing text
set textwidth=78
```

and

```
" 25. Language specific
autocmd ColorScheme * if &filetype == 'markdown' | highlight link markdownerror normal | endif
autocmd Filetype markdown highlight link markdownerror normal

" 27. Various
colorscheme Slate
```

where an additional `if &filetype ... endif` has been added for the to check if the current file is of a markdown filetype. In this case, the `Filetype` event is also needed, for example, when the colorscheme is changed before a markdown file is opened.

Answer (score 1):

It is a truth universally acknowledged that the order just matters.

```
:set colorcolumn& textwidth&   " &cc=""  &tw=0
:let &colorcolumn = &textwidth " &cc="0" &tw=0
:set textwidth=78              " &cc="0" &tw=78

:hi markdownError              " E411: Highlight group not found
:hi link markdownError Normal  " links to Normal
:colorscheme foobar
    "hi clear                  " <-- sic
    "hi xxx
    "hi yyy
    "...
:hi markdownError              " xxx cleared
```

But there are also some tricks.

```
set colorcolumn=+0                " current value of &tw + 0
hi def link markdownError Normal  " lowest priority; used only when cleared
```